# Source for multipolygon data?

Tags: postgis, data, united-kingdom, germany

I have a PostGIS database where I would like to store multipolygon data of certain cities.

The type of the table column is `geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)`.

I'm now looking for a source where I can get the multipolygon data for cities like London or Berlin or a tool that supports me in creating this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OSM data](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100) springs to mind.  You can get the data you need from OSM or bundles from [Geofabrik](http://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html) (among other providers).  If you use the tool [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) to import to PostGIS, there is a switch that will import the data as multigeometries (see description of the -G switch [here](http://www.volkerschatz.com/net/osm/osm2pgsql-usage.html)).  The default import is Web Mercator but you can tell osm2pgsql to use EPSG:4326.

After OSM, there are many other sources, such as national mapping agencies for the countries concerned (e.g. Ordnance Survey for GB etc).  However, OSM will give you a one-stop-shop.